# How to configure SASS to output shorthand hex colors

Tags: css, configuration, colors, sass, shorthand

Is there any way to make SASS or Compass give you a shortened hex color? For example, if I type `#444` it gives me `#444444` in my output file, which isn't a real optimization help for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The color codes are optimized only when the output style is set to *compressed*.

```
// style.scss
$primary-color: #444;
$secondary-color: #ffffff;
.test {
  background: $primary-color;
  color: $secondary-color;
}
```

compiled with the command `sass -t compressed style.scss style.css` produce the following file:

```
// style.css
.test{background:#444;color:#fff}
```